# Set tab title to GNOME terminal window

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, gnome

I know this looks like it's been asked before but here's an additional twist.

I was researching the answer to this question and I found a lot of hints about PROMPT_COMMAND (in /etc/bashrc) and escape sequence "\033]0;TITLE\007".

This all works fine when applied to a freshly opened tab but it fails as soon as I have set a title manually via the menu's "set title" window function. When I remove my "sticky" title setting with the window menu I can again use the escape sequence.

Is it possible to override that setting and have it set the title unconditionally?

Bonus question: is it possible to *read* the current title (i.e. to save the old title, run some script which does status messages via the tab's title, then restores the tab title upon exit).